# compute function in neuralnet R package not working when reproduced

Tags: r, excel, neural-network

I trained a model in `neuralnet` and I am trying to figure out how to compute results in Excel. Using the `compute` function that you call from the package everything works fine. But I went into the source code using F2 in Rstudio and the [github page](https://github.com/cran/neuralnet/blob/master/R/compute.r) and the function is not working and stops on the `relist()` function and gives the error: `Error in relist(weights, nrow.weights, ncol.weights) : 
  unused argument (ncol.weights)`

I think the problem is the `relist(`) function but I do not know how to transform the weights without it. And the `neuralnet` package does not come with its own version of `relist()`. If you ignore the relist line you get the following error: `Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments` because the `weights` wasn't transformed correctly. I tried the same thing on my own data and got the same error.

```
library(neuralnet)
normalize <-function(x) {
  return((x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)))
} 
newdf <- Cars93
newdf = na.omit(newdf)
newdf <- newdf[complete.cases(newdf),]
newdf$Cylinders <- as.numeric(levels(newdf$Cylinders))[newdf$Cylinders]
newdf$Horsepower <- normalize(newdf$Horsepower)
newdf$EngineSize <- normalize(newdf$EngineSize)
newdf$Cylinders <- normalize(newdf$Cylinders)
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(newdf))
set.seed(12)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(newdf)), size = smp_size)
train <- newdf[train_ind, ]
test <- newdf[-train_ind, ]

carsNN <- neuralnet(Horsepower ~ Cylinders+EngineSize,
                    data = train,hidden = c(1))
cars_results = compute(carsNN,test[11:12])

#this is the source code using F2 in RStudio and on github
sourceCodeCompute = function (x, covariate, rep = 1) 
{
  nn <- x
  linear.output <- nn$linear.output
  weights <- nn$weights[[rep]]
  nrow.weights <- sapply(weights, nrow)
  ncol.weights <- sapply(weights, ncol)
  weights <- unlist(weights)
  if (any(is.na(weights))) 
    weights[is.na(weights)] <- 0
  weights <- relist(weights, nrow.weights, ncol.weights)
  length.weights <- length(weights)
  covariate <- as.matrix(cbind(1, covariate))
  act.fct <- nn$act.fct
  neurons <- list(covariate)
  if (length.weights > 1) 
    for (i in 1:(length.weights - 1)) {
      temp <- neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]]
      act.temp <- act.fct(temp)
      neurons[[i + 1]] <- cbind(1, act.temp)
    }
  temp <- neurons[[length.weights]] %*% weights[[length.weights]]
  if (linear.output) 
    net.result <- temp
  else net.result <- act.fct(temp)
  list(neurons = neurons, net.result = net.result)
}

sourceCodeCompute(carsNN,test[11:12])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong `relist` function. Try explicitly calling [`neuralnet:::relist`](https://github.com/cran/neuralnet/blob/master/R/neuralnet.r#L834), which is the (unexported) function used automatically within the package namespace.

(I don't know how this question relates to Excel.)